# Distribution of a Sum of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables. What is the distribution of $X+Y$, in terms of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, which are $P \circ X^{-1}(\infty, x]$ and $P \circ Y^{-1}(\infty, y]$ respectively? I've looked online and it said that the distribution of the sum is the convolution of the distributions, but my textbook says the convolution of the distributions is the distribution for $XY$, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: The convolution of the distributions is indeed the distribution of the sum (if the variables are independant), not the product.

Comment: It's probably just a typo in the book.